# Draw 3 lines of count elements by day using highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a `Array` with 4 JSON objects.
Each object contain a **date** (in ms) format, and a **severity**. I would like to display **3 lines into a chart** :

```
var alarmArray = [];

var alarm1 = {
    date : 1444808062
    severity : "minor"
};
alarmArray.push(alarm1);

var alarm2 = {
    date : 1444808061
    severity : "critical"
};
alarmArray.push(alarm2);

var alarm3 = {
    date : 1444808065
    severity : "minor"
};
alarmArray.push(alarm3);

var alarm4 = {
    date : 1444808090
    severity : "major"
};
alarmArray.push(alarm4);
```

- 1 line for the number of minor alarm by day
- 1 line for the number of major alarm by day
- 1 line for the number of critical alarm by day

Is it possible to do that with highcharts ? using date in milliseconds ? ([like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-irregular-time/)) ?

Comment: line connects two points , if you have only one time-value in each object how will be line created ? Will each day have only one alarm?

Comment: If each timestamp (ms) has only one value how will that connect because it has no other point. Or if you have how many alarms were Major,minor,critical you can create column chart . I created chart for major minor critical occurring for a time range: See this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/